# How can I make my BlackBerry java program wait till a core app is opened before proceeding?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

My BlackBerry Java program opens the calender app. After that is opened I want it to do something but I currently just use a 250 millisecond delay before that happens. Sometimes the calender take longer or shorter to open. Is there a simple way to use like a Javascript type "While" action in Java for this? Like this English:

Open Calendar
While "calendar is not open" wait
(then the rest of the program after this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [getVisibleApplications() in the ApplicationManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#getVisibleApplications%28%29) class will return all applications that are currently running and that can come to the foreground.  I would repeatedly search through the array that gives you until the Calendar application shows up.